# Error with pip install biom-format on macbook pro

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, biom

I am failing to install biom format using pip install biom-format on my macbook pro. This is the error I get

```
Nawaz$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Nawaz$ pip install biom-format
Collecting biom-format
  Using cached biom-format-2.1.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: click in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from biom-format)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.3.0 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from biom-format)
Requirement already satisfied: future>=0.14.3 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from biom-format)
Collecting scipy>=0.13.0 (from biom-format)
  Using cached scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting pyqi (from biom-format)
Installing collected packages: scipy, pyqi, biom-format
  Found existing installation: scipy 0.13.0b1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scipy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling scipy-0.13.0b1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/jv/nt6x1lw17z35xqzr5y64f89w0000gn/T/pip-5V1mGE-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy-0.13.0b1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

please help me with the error removal.

Comment: did you use `sudo`?

Comment: or better check virtualenvironment package [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Comment: you can also use pip3 freeze to see if it actually did install anyway

Comment: I tried with the sudo option but there comes the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install things globally try using sudo.

If you only want things in an isolated environment use virtualenv.

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#usage

Hopefully this will solve your problem